# Write formula in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

**Hi!**

[image]

Can any one show me example, how I can write this in Excel.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for minus, but maiby you can give me some information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=IF(AND(200<=A1,A1<340),1,IF(AND(27<=A1,A1<80),2,IF(AND(16<=A1,A1<24),3,IF(AND(5<=A1,A1<12),4,IF(AND(-10<=A1,A1<2),5,"X")))))
```

This represents your logic as nested *ifs.*  The ***X*** represents the *else*.

*(this assumes the syntax of your Post conveys 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as the values of the output.)*

**EDIT#1:**

This formula handles the ***500*** case:

```
=IF(OR(AND(200<=A1,A1<340),A1=500),1,IF(AND(27<=A1,A1<80),2,IF(AND(16<=A1,A1<24),3,IF(AND(5<=A1,A1<12),4,IF(AND(-10<=A1,A1<2),5,"X")))))
```

Comment: Thanks very match!

Comment: As I understand, A1 means 500?

Comment: For example: http://barber.dp.ua/1.jpg
It will be:
=IF(AND(56<=A1,A1<570),1,IF(AND(45<=A1,A1<52),2,IF(AND(25<=A1,A1<40),3,IF(AND(16<=A1,A1<10),4,IF(AND(1<=A1,A1<2),5,"X")))))

?

Comment: @ShkarbatovDmitriy  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I get it, it will be: 
=IF(AND(56<=A1,A1<570),1,IF(AND(45<=A1,A1<52),2,IF(AND(25<=A‌​1,A1<40),3,IF(OR(AND(16‌​<=A1,A1<10),A1=15),4,IF(AND‌​(1<=A1,A1<2),5,"X"))‌​)))